# ipython from emacs on windows XP, no prompt and no print output

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

I want to integrate ipython to emacs 23, on windows XP.
I could find quite some information online, but nothing did the trick.

The following is required in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

- python-mode
- pymacs
- ipython

pyreadline is also installed.

I launch ipython with a bat file (in my system path), with the flags -i and -u.

The information text

```
c:\Program\emacs-23.2\bin>c:\program\python27\scripts\ipython -i -u

Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.10.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object'. ?object also works, ?? prints more.
```

does not appear until I write the first command.

I get no prompt.
Writing and "executing" numbers do result in the red "`Out[n]:`" and the number.
`Print` does not give anything.
`a` gives the a colorful ipython error text, ending with `NameError: name 'a' not defined`.

In other words, the error stream seems ok, the standard output seems ok, but `print` and whatever is responsible for printing the prompt cannot seem to find the correct stream.

---

emacs `*Message*` buffer says:

```
comint-send-string: Output file descriptor of Python<1> is closed
```

for every output (not appearing) in the python shell.

Comment: @Natan: nope, I use a separate prompt.

Comment: I have exact same problem with emacs 24.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using [pyreadline 1.6](https://launchpad.net/pyreadline/1.6/1.6). Version 1.5 writes to the stream using the console API even when run via Emacs. That causes many problems similar to the ones you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My version of pyreadline is 1.6.1.win32.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is the Python interpreter itself and not the ipython script which is to receive the `-u` parameter, i.e. your file `C:\Program\Python27\scripts\ipython.bat` should contain something like:

```
@C:\Program\Python27\python.exe -u C:\Program\Python27\scripts\ipython.py %*
```

Comment: Since the %* is there, the `-u` argument should be passed through anyway? Does it matter if `-u -i` is before or after the name of the python script?

Comment: Yes, it matters. Usually, the interpreter ignores all options after the script name, assuming they are meant for the script.

Comment: I see. I tested this with no luck. As I wrote in my update, I get "Output file descriptor of Python is closed".