# IPython in Emacs on Windows, no prompt appears

Tags: windows, emacs, ipython

I want to use IPython in Emacs 24.4 on Windows 8.1. In order to do this, I use elpy in my .emacs file, and have included commands to launch IPython when I execute code in Emacs. My problem is similar to the one listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468935/ipython-from-emacs-on-windows-xp-no-prompt-and-no-print-output/) with a few caveats:

- If I'm running something very basic (i.e. print "Hello World") IPython won't output anything.
- If I'm using a module like matplotlib, IPython will display the plots and print any materials that I ask it to print in the file, while displaying the usual "prompts.

It's very possible that there is an answer out there and I simply don't know the terminology to find it, so any advice would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your .emacs file:

```
(package-initialize)
(elpy-enable)
(elpy-use-ipython)
(setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi")

(setq python-shell-interpreter "C:\\python27\\python.exe"
       python-shell-interpreter-args
       "-i C:\\python27\\Scripts\\ipython-script.py console --pylab=qt")
```

I had the exact problem you're refering to, and the problem seems to be that ipython demands a bit of tweaking for windows (the three last lines above), and elpy seems to override these.

Hope this helps.